# How to start plugin FullPage.js when browser window is resized from mobile to tablet and up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Using fullPage.js, I disabled the plugin when window size is lower then 767px with the code below. It works, but when I resize it back from below 767px to something like 960px, the plugin doesn't work. Can anyone help restart the plugin after resizing?

JS:
    function fullPageScroll() {
        $('#main').fullpage({
            navigation: true
        });
    }

```
var $win = $(window).width();

if ( $win > 767 ) {
    fullPageScroll();
} else {
    fullPageScroll();
    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you also need to apply that on the resize event:

```
//first call when loading the site
doneResizing()

var resizeId;
//calling the function again  on resize so we can get the new width
$(window).resize(function () {
    //in order to call the functions only when the resize is finished
    clearTimeout(resizeId);

    resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

//your original code
function doneResizing() {
    var $win = $(window).width();

    if ($win > 767) {
        fullPageScroll();
    } else {
        fullPageScroll();
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use this

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    #scroll-section{
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    }
    body {
        overflow: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only turn `autoScroll:true` if `css3:true`. It won't destroy the effect of fullpage.js on the site and will not work in all cases. 
Always use the libraries functions when possible.